# sportbug is not working in eclipse Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, spotbugs

i have installed plugin SpotBugs 4.7.3.r202210170504-fa9e53a in eclipse Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0). i am using java SE 8. while running spotbug in my project getting exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse".
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:211)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getStream(URLImageDescriptor.java:139)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getImageData(URLImageDescriptor.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getImageData(URLImageDescriptor.java:85)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:268)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.TrimStack.getImage(TrimStack.java:816)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.TrimStack.updateTrimStackItems(TrimStack.java:881)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.TrimStack.createWidget(TrimStack.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:995)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:403)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:344)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
```

[image: spotbug documention].

I am using latest version still getting this error. could some one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: In what way did you install SpotBugs (there are several ways, so describe exactly each step you did)? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (the stack trace is not enough and it's unclear where you got it from).

Comment: @howlger I have downloaded spotbug from eclipse marketplace

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Does it work with the current version of Eclipse and a fresh workspace?

Comment: @howlger for upgraded version with fresh workspace. i am getting error this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FGj_Dgdp5-nW9XC37iMRdojwAFiNaEIy/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: That's not an error, just a warning which has [already reported here](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/2155). Does it work with the upgraded version and the fresh workspace?